# How can I grep for text that contains a single and double quote?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Also, I want to keep some type of outer quotes so that I can use a large regular expression.

For example, if file 'Test' contains literal:  `"Josh's Dog"`

I do `grep '"Josh's Dog"' test`

and it doesn't work.

What do I need to escape out of?

Comment: You need to provide more information than this. We can't perform magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
grep \"Josh\'s\ Dog\" test
```

Or as noted here [Why escaped single quote doesn't work in grep?](https://superuser.com/questions/597874/why-escaped-single-quote-doesnt-work-in-grep), try

```
grep -P '"Josh\047s Dog"' dat
```

Comment: The second one, is it!!  Thank you

Comment: @N00b101 Yes.  The first doesn't contain any quotes for the pattern.  The second contains single quotes and replace the `'` in the string with a hex value.